# input submit empty, using nativescript

Tags: android, typescript, mobile, input, nativescript

I want to register user, but my input value submit empty:

I  follow step by step this [code](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/07/simple-login-registration-nativescript-angular-mobile-app/). I can't see any problem in my code. Any idea please?

Component.html

```
 <GridLayout backgroundColor="#CCCCCC">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center">
                <StackLayout class="form" padding="15" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
                    <StackLayout class="input-field">
                        <Label text="First Name" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
                        <TextField class="input" value="input.firstname"></TextField>
                        <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout class="input-field">
                        <Label text="Last Name" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
                        <TextField class="input" [(ngModel)]="input.lastname"></TextField>
                        <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout class="input-field">
                        <Label text="Email" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
                        <TextField class="input" [(ngModel)]="input.email"></TextField>
                        <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout class="input-field">
                        <Label text="Password" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
                        <TextField  secure="true" [(ngModel)]="input.password" class="input" required></TextField>
                        <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Button class="btn btn-primary w-full" text="Register" (tap)="register()"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>
```

Component.ts

```
export class RegisterComponent {
    public input: any;
    public constructor(private location: Location) {
        this.input = {
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "email": "",
            "password": ""
        }
    }
      public register() {
        if(this.input.firstname && this.input.lastname && this.input.email && this.input.password) {
            ApplicationSettings.setString("account", JSON.stringify(this.input));
            this.location.back();
        } else {
            (new SnackBar()).simple("All Fields Required!");
        }
    }}
```

I can't understand why my value submit empty!! Can you ask me any idea please?

Comment: ngModel for firstname is missing

Answer (score 0):

To enable two-way binding check if you are importing `NativeScriptFormsModule` in the related module. If your application is not using lazy loading that should be the main `app.module.ts`

```
// Uncomment and add to NgModule imports if you need to use two-way binding
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

imports: [
    NativeScriptFormsModule // ADD it to imports
],
```

Note that the code you have shared is only saving a key-value in the application settings which you should later reuse for logging in the user (by accessing the specific key `account`.